# Matlab Arduino serial communication in real-time with 0.004 s sampling

Tags: matlab, real-time, arduino-uno, serial-communication

I am trying to do a real-time communication with matlab and an arduino Uno. The idea is to send motor commands in PWM, and read the sensor values. But first I would want to have a real-time communication on the serial/USB.

For this reason the arduino code is waiting for the call from matlab, and depending on the type of the call the answer will be forwarded to the motor (control command) or the encoder value will be sent to the laptop (read command).

In the matlab part I used the serial object, and I opened at a high baudrate. When I checked the timing in matlab using the profiler, it looks like the problem is not from the matlab side, but from the arduino/ or serial communication.

The problem is that for some reason I need a very small sampling time around 0.004 s. but I could not achieve this, no matter how big is the baud rate. What should I change in order to have a faster communication? It is important to mention that I need a real-time control. Using 0.004, I get some very noisy data with a mean value around 0.015; but still if I change it to 0.015 some peaks appear.

For a better understanding here is the arduino code:

```
const byte numChars = 8;
char receivedChars[numChars];   // an array to store the received data
int numb = 0;
boolean newData = false;
void setup() { 
   Serial.begin(250000);
   Serial.setTimeout(100);
} 
void loop() {
   recvWithEndMarker();
   showNewData();
}

void recvWithEndMarker() {
static byte ndx = 0;
char endMarker = '>';
char rc;

while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
    rc = Serial.read();

    if (rc != endMarker) {
        receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
        ndx++;
        if (ndx >= numChars) {
            ndx = numChars - 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
        ndx = 0;
        newData = true;
    }
}
numb = atoi(receivedChars);
}

void showNewData() {
if (newData == true) {
    if (numb==256)
      Serial.println(numb);
    newData = false;
}
}'
```

And here is the MATLAB code

```
for k = 1:N,
    % time(k)
    alpha(k) = utread;
    %simple constant input, here goes the control algorithm
 %     u(k) = (-1 + k/255);
    u(k) = sign(mod(k,5)-2);
 %     for aaa=1:100
 %     1+2;
 %     end
    utwrite(u(k));
    %synchronize, wait for next sample time
    time(k+1) = toc;
    while(time(k+1)<(time(k)+Ts))
        time(k+1) = toc;
    end  
end
```

for simplicity I put just the most important part.
and utread is a function having the form:

```
utread.m
global utip
fprintf(utip.s,'256>');
dat = fscanf(utip.s,'%d');
while (isempty(dat)) % wait for data on the serial
    fprintf(utip.s,'256>');
    dat = fscanf(utip.s,'%d');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a latency timer issue at the host side, which has default of 16 ms. Is your USB-serial chip from FTDI? If so, you will need to set the LatencyTimer to the shortest 1ms. Then the OS will update serial buffer at 1ms interval rather than 16 ms interval.

If this is the cause, you can google how to change latency timer for your OS. New MAC OS may have no good solution at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to solve with this, but the problem is following: an arduino Uno instead of an FTDI, uses an atmega16u for serial-USB communication, where it is not so easy to change the LatencyTimer (no direct acces from Device Manager).

Comment: So it uses single chip VUSB solution?

Comment: Well, it is a separate chip, not the same one as Arduino uses (2 atmega chips: atmega 328p atmega16u).

Comment: You can get USB-TTL cables that use the FTDI chip in them, then connect to the UART pins on the arduino. You don’t have to use the on-board atmega16u for the VCP.